# Why bloodmoon rising and other coop no longer exist in overwatch arcade?

Tags: overwatch

All I see is this competitive open queue. And it's been that way for so long.

And I can't play that game. The wait time is like 30 minutes to 1 hour.

So, do I have to play it so this competitive open queue go away?

It's been 2 months the only game in competitive game.

Answer (score 2):

Bloodmoon Rising is one of the Archives challenge modes.  As such, it's only around during the Archives event and certain days of the Anniversary event (which rotates event modes on a daily basis).

Right now, there are no events running.  The next event will be the Summer Games event, which usually starts in mid-July/early-August.

On a side note, there are always 7 arcade modes available.  Mystery Heroes and Quickplay Classic are always available, 3 cards rotate daily, and the rest are either taken up by special modes or rotate daily.

Comment: so it'll be a long time before it shows up again?

Comment: It won't reappear until sometime in March 2021.